# Embed Javafx into swing application

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I have a huge swing application and I wanted to embed javafx into it.
I tried many times to do that (by following oracle tutorials etc) and I only succeed when I declared a new JFrame to use the JFXPanel component. But, I don't want to use a new Frame, I want to incorporate my Javafx code into the root JFrame of the swing application.

Can we embed javaFX components into JPanel instead of JFrame ?
If the answer is yes, why didn't I succeed ?

There is the code sample that is probably wrong :

This class directly extends JPanel and the initialize method is called in an EDT

```
private void initialize(){

  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
  JPanel jp = new JPanel();

  jp.add(fxPanel);
  jp.setVisible(true);
  jp.setSize(500, 300);
  jp.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

  Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
     initFX(fxPanel);
     }
  });

  add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(jp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}


private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
  Scene scene = initScene();
  fxPanel.setScene(scene);
}


private static Scene initScene(){

  Group  root  =  new  Group();
  Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, javafx.scene.paint.Color.ALICEBLUE );
  Text  text  =  new  Text();
  text.setX(40);
  text.setY(100);
  text.setFont(new Font(25));
  text.setText("Welcome JavaFX!");
  root.getChildren().add(text);
  return (scene);

}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: In fact, the JavaFX content in my JPanel is hidden. We can only see the swing components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally**, I found a way to make the javafx works. I made my `SwingJFXCombo`class inherit from an abstract class `SimplePullerPanel`that provides methods to handle pulling (`SimplePullerPanel`extends the abstract class `PullerPanel`which extends JPanel ).
To make that work I override the `buildContentPanel` method in our `SwingJFXCombo`class

```
public abstract class SimplePullerPanel extends PullerPanel implements PropertyChangeListener
{
     ...

    protected abstract JComponent buildContentPanel();

    @Override
    protected void buildPanel()
    {

        JComponent oContentPanel = buildContentPanel();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(oContentPanel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

     ...
}

public class SwingJFXCombo extends SimplePullerPanel{

    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    public SwingJFXCombo(){
        setName("fx sample"); 
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createScene(){
        Group  root  =  new  Group();
        Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, javafx.scene.paint.Color.ALICEBLUE );

        Text  text  =  new  Text();
        text.setX(40);
        text.setY(100);
        text.setFont(new Font(25));
        text.setText("Welcome JavaFX!");
        root.getChildren().add(text);
        return (scene);
    }

    @Override
    protected JComponent buildContentPanel()
    {
        JPanel frame = new JPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });
        return frame;
    }
}
```

It doesn't explain why the previous code doesn't work and I noticed that if I want to create my custom `SimplePullerPanel` by deleting some methods that I don't use I face the same problem.
Very strange

Answer (score 2):

Took your code, turned it into a SSCCE - everything seems to work, which would indicate the problem is elsewhere in your code.  Can you reproduce your problem using this code?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingJFXCombo {

    public static Container initialize(){

        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();

        jp.add(fxPanel);
        jp.setVisible(true);
        // Really shouldn't do this, so commented it out
        //jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        jp.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });

        return jp;
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Scene scene = initScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene initScene(){
        Group  root  =  new  Group();
        Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, javafx.scene.paint.Color.ALICEBLUE );
        Text  text  =  new  Text();
        text.setX(40);
        text.setY(100);
        text.setFont(new Font(25));
        text.setText("Welcome JavaFX!");
        root.getChildren().add(text);
        return (scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(SwingJFXCombo.initialize());
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer Nick.
Well, your code works for me in a SSCCE but when I tried to incorporate it in my application the same problem happened.
It indicates that the problem is elsewhere in my code, but,what could be the thing that prevent the javafx execution ?

Comment: I'd suggest putting a print statement in the  `Platform.runLater` call and the `initialize` call to see if those methods are getting called.  Determining which methods are getting called and which aren't would be a good first step.

Comment: I put print statements where you've told me, in the `initScene` call and the `initFX` call too and it seems like all methods are getting called

Comment: Hrm.  That's strange.  I guess then I'd recommend you copy your code into a new project and just start tearing out pieces until you have a runnable, simple, self contained example that reproduces your problem (like the sample I provided, only it shows the problem).  Either you'll be able to show us the problem, or you'll figure out exactly which piece of code is causing the problem... either way it'll give us more to work with.